# By Code, print the PDF file using the "Microsoft Print To PDF" option without prompting for the filename or target location window using Python

Tags: python, windows, python-3.7

Currently I am using win32api methods ShellExecute to print the pdf using the "Microsoft Print to PDF" option to print the PDF. But when I use this, a windows prompt appears which asks for the file name for the print document. Is there a way i can code the path and the file name of the target pdf and allow the prompt to appear on the screen using Python.

Comment: Question already asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68653912/python-microsoft-print-to-pdf and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66721163/python-print-to-pdf  and the answer seems to be that you can't do that easily.

Comment: @kj Can you please elaborate? Is it python way of doing it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.